# How to call Iframe JavaScript function inside my page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have Iframe in side my page, In that below javascript is there.

```
    function getTotSeats(){
    window.WebAppInterface.showToast(document.forms[0].txtSeat_no.value);
    return document.forms[0].txtSeat_no.value;
}
```

I want to call above javascipt function in my page.

My page is

```
<iframe name="select_frame" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" id="iframe_id" src="http://202.65.147.152:8080/tgtdc/etg/seatLayoutReservation.jsp?upDown=UP&toCityCode=100&serviceCode=34&totSeats=2&vehicle=HITECH%20-%20AC&toDate=31-08-2015&FR=F" width=100% style="z-index:10000" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none;"></iframe>
<input type='button' name='save' value='SAVE' id="save_id" style="height:30px;width:100px;">
<script>

    $('#save_id').click(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('iframe_id');

    var result=getIframeWindow(el).getTotSeats();
    alert(result);

});
```

But I am not getting the iframe function value in my page.How do I get that value.Can you please any body help me.

Comment: If the iframe's domain (`http://202.65.147.152:8080/`) is different to that of the parent window then you will not be able to access it's content due to the security features of the browser.

Comment: Yes 'http://202.65.147.152:8080/ '  is a different server, I am working on there server.But I need to use that values.Is it not possible.?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because of the same-origin policy. You could look in to Cross-window messaging with postMessage.

http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage